# Please, help me understand an example from Folland.

Tags: real-analysis

Chapter 1. Borel measures.

> Let $\{ r_j\}_j^\infty$ be an enumeration of rational numbers in [0,1], and given $\epsilon>0$, let $I_j$ be an open interval around $r_j$ of length $\epsilon 2^{-j}$. Then the set $U=(0,1)\cap \cup_1^\infty I_j$ is open and dense in [0, 1], but $m(u)\leq \sum_1^\infty \epsilon 2^{-j}=\epsilon$; its complement $K=[0,1]\setminus U$ is closed and nowhere dense, but $m(K)=1-\epsilon$.

This example contradicts my intuition. If $K$ is nowhere dense, then its closure should not contain any open interval. If this is the case, the Lebesgue measure of $K$ should be equal to zero, not positive. Plese, help me out here.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted; to me, the OP demonstrates some effort to understand the problem and provides initial thoughts. Upvoted to offset.

Comment: When confronted with facts that contradict intuition, some people protect their intuition and attack the facts. Others fine tune their intuition. What kind of person are you OP?

Comment: Second type. Trying to work on my intuition ;)

Comment: Why should a closed nowhere dense set be of measure 0? That seems to be your key claim.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set#Nowhere_dense_sets_with_positive_measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the intuition is that it is based on real life. This makes it fail sometimes when dealing with infinite, and especially uncountable sets.

Your intuition tells you that if a set has positive measure, then it must contain an interval. We that is not true, try to prove it and you'll see. The set $K$ above is a counterexample.  Another simple example is the [Cantor set of positive measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) (this type of set is a good source for many "counterintuitive" properties)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.